# REST API support for Apple HealthKit data

Tags: api, rest, healthkit, fitness, applehealth

Is there a REST API support to query apple health kit data? I want to fetch these data from a server application on behalf of a user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query HealthKit data via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985672/query-healthkit-data-via-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

No. HealthKit data is only available on-device.